# how to use warpPerspective on creating panoramic image (opencv)?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, panoramas

i am trying to make a simple code to stitch two images using Surf detector, FLANN matcher and using findHomograpy.
my project is based on this project :
http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/
the problem is, the result image is not as expected. i think the problem lies on wrapping image process, because instead of combined result of two images, mine show only specific area which exist in both images.

(because of link restriction, i merge my result image and my expected result)
[mine is on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zvgq.jpg)

Comment: you may show us some code.. but please try to make it as tiny as possible

Comment: the blending part of that sample code is bad. you should replace it. but you'll have to understand the code/method first.

Comment: Note that there is now an entire pipeline for creating panoramic images in OpenCV, if your final goal is panoramas maybe have a look at it. It's in the stitching namespace. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/stitching.html